# How to make a subclass conform to a protocol in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, protocols

I have a protocol which a base class implements. I have subclasses for which I want to enforce the protocol.

```
@class JSData;

@protocol JSDataProtocol <NSObject, NSCopying, NSMutableCopying>
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *dataType;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) id value;
- (JSData *)value;
- (BOOL)hasMeta;
// ...
@end
```

The base class is

```
@interface JSData : NSObject <JSDataProtocol, JSHashable, JSEquatable>
@end
```

I am then creating other classes like

```
@interface JSSymbol: JSData
- (NSString *)name;
- (JSData *)value;
@end
```

But the problem here is since `JSData` conforms to `JSDataProtocol`, if I missed implementing some method in `JSSymbol`, Xcode does not show any warning and I get runtime error. Is there a way to enforce that `JSSymbol` implements all methods defined in the `JSDataProtocol`?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Those methods in your protocol are required. Xcode should be giving you compiler errors.

Comment: Updated my question. Warning does not show in `JSSymbol`.

Comment: If JSData conforms to JSDataProtocol, in other words it implements the required methods, then you won't get a warning about JSSymbol because its superclass conforms. In that case your runtime error is about something else.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure that `JSSymbol` implements (or overrides) these methods. For example `type` method should return `"symbol"` if implemented. Else it will return the one from base which will be say `"data"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSSymbol` derives from `JSData`, which already implements the `JSDataProtocol` methods. So **no**, you can't get compile-time errors for not implementing those methods.

If you really want this, you could either:

- move the `JSDataProtocol` declaration from `JSData` down to the concrete classes.
- get rid of `JSData` entirely and make `JSDataProtocol` inherit from `JSHashable` & `JSEquatable`

If you get rid of `JSData`, your protocol definition can be streamlined to:

```
@protocol JSDataProtocol <NSObject, NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, 
                          JSHashable, JSEquatable>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *dataType;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) id<JSDataProtocol> value;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL hasMeta;

@end
```

Comment: In that case of the second option, what should the type be for `- (JSData *)value;` in `JSSymbol`? If I give `(JSDataProtocol *)value;`, I get `Expected a type`.

Comment: Added to the answer for this. You want the `id<MyProtocol>` syntax, I'm pretty sure.